# Can I trade in off-hours and if not what does the graph shows in that case?

Tags: stocks, stock-exchanges, after-hours-trading

I new to trading and I would like to know why the graph of the stock after closing still follows a path up and down and why it is not a straight line.

Can I trade using on the weekend using the gray graph shown?

Is there any significance of this path/graph in the after hours?  Does it affect anything or offer
anything valuable that I can use to some advantage?

[image: Stocks in the after hours]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the US, pre-market trading is from 4 a.m. to 9:30 a.m. EST and after-hours trading is from 4 p.m. to 8 p.m. on weekdays.  Some collectively call both after hours trading.

Some brokers do not offer after hours trading.  For those that do, it often requires that you get approval to do so, usually just a formality.

After hours trading tends to be more volatile with larger bid/ask spreads due to illiquidity.  You need to be quick thinking and  decisive because price can turn on a dime.

Comment: Good to know. Thanks!

Yes the graph stopped at 8pm :)